# Spring Integration not moving file after processing

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

My requirement is to move files from input to output directory. Currently, I receive an XML file, parse it, process it and would like to move to new folder. I am using SPring boot 2.0, Spring INtegration 5. Attached is the code. This integration flows process the file but after processing it is not moving the file new directory.

Could you please let me know what is missing and how to fix this?

Logs are

```
2018-04-06 15:55:16.473[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m6364[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ask-scheduler-1][0;39m [36mo.s.i.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m handler 'ServiceActivator for [org.springframework.integration.handler.BeanNameMessageProcessor@33a55bd8] (org.springframework.integration.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler#0)' produced no reply for request Message: GenericMessage [payload=Producers {id: -2147483648, parent-id: 0}, headers={file_originalFile=C:\slim\OBDF\Entire_IMO_hierarchy.xml, id=3ee00fca-1f2b-be84-742a-b5c6edfaf42a, file_name=Entire_IMO_hierarchy.xml, file_relativePath=Entire_IMO_hierarchy.xml, timestamp=1523055316426}]
2018-04-06 15:55:16.475[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m6364[0;39m ---[0;39m [ask-scheduler-1][0;39m [36mo.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel   [0;39m :[0;39m postSend (sent=true) on channel 'slimflow.channel#1', message: GenericMessage [payload=Producers {id: -2147483648, parent-id: 0}, headers={file_originalFile=C:\slim\OBDF\Entire_IMO_hierarchy.xml, id=3ee00fca-1f2b-be84-742a-b5c6edfaf42a, file_name=Entire_IMO_hierarchy.xml, file_relativePath=Entire_IMO_hierarchy.xml, timestamp=1523055316426}]
2018-04-06 15:55:16.480[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m6364[0;39m ---[0;39m [ask-scheduler-1][0;39m [36mo.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel   [0;39m :[0;39m postSend (sent=true) on channel 'slimflow.channel#0', message: GenericMessage [payload=C:\slim\OBDF\Entire_IMO_hierarchy.xml, headers={file_originalFile=C:\slim\OBDF\Entire_IMO_hierarchy.xml, id=0f673954-bceb-6e64-0d47-639522002569, file_name=Entire_IMO_hierarchy.xml, file_relativePath=Entire_IMO_hierarchy.xml, timestamp=1523055316320}]
```

Integration flow config

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.function.Function;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel;
import org.springframework.integration.config.EnableIntegration;
import org.springframework.integration.core.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlow;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlows;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.Pollers;
import org.springframework.integration.file.FileReadingMessageSource;
import org.springframework.integration.file.FileWritingMessageHandler;
import org.springframework.integration.file.filters.AcceptOnceFileListFilter;
import org.springframework.integration.file.filters.ChainFileListFilter;
import org.springframework.integration.file.filters.RegexPatternFileListFilter;
import org.springframework.integration.transformer.PayloadTypeConvertingTransformer;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandler;

@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
public class SlimIntegrationConfig {
    @Value("${input.directory}")
    private String inputDir;

    @Value("${outputDir.directory}")
    private String outputDir;

    @Value("${input.scan.frequency: 100000}")
    private long scanFrequency;

    @Autowired
    private XmlBeanExtractor<Producers> xmlBeanExtractor;

    @Bean
    public MessageSource<File> inputFileSource() {
        FileReadingMessageSource src = new FileReadingMessageSource(
                (f1, f2) -> Long.valueOf(f1.lastModified()).compareTo(f2.lastModified()));

        src.setDirectory(new File(inputDir));
        src.setAutoCreateDirectory(true);

        ChainFileListFilter<File> chainFileListFilter = new ChainFileListFilter<>();        
        chainFileListFilter.addFilter(new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<>() );
        chainFileListFilter.addFilter(new RegexPatternFileListFilter("(?i)^.+\\.xml$"));        
        src.setFilter(chainFileListFilter);

        return src;
    }

    @Bean
    public DirectChannel outputChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageHandler fileOutboundChannelAdapter() {

        FileWritingMessageHandler adapter = new FileWritingMessageHandler(new File(outputDir));
        adapter.setDeleteSourceFiles(true);
        adapter.setAutoCreateDirectory(true);
        adapter.setExpectReply(false);
        return adapter;
    }

    @Bean
    PayloadTypeConvertingTransformer<File, Producers> xmlBeanTranformer() {
        PayloadTypeConvertingTransformer<File, Producers> tranformer = new PayloadTypeConvertingTransformer<>();
        tranformer.setConverter(file -> {
            Producers p = null;
            try {
                p = xmlBeanExtractor.extract(file.getAbsolutePath(), Producers.class);
            } catch (JAXBException | XMLStreamException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return p;
        });

        return tranformer;
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow slimflow() {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(inputFileSource(), spec -> spec.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(scanFrequency)))
                .transform(xmlBeanTranformer())
                .handle("slimFileProcessor","processfile")
                .channel(outputChannel())
                .handle(fileOutboundChannelAdapter())
                .get()
                ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need top know what your `slimFileProcessor.processfile()` does. However it doesn't reflect what you do in the `xmlBeanTranformer`. You convert there a `File` payload to the `Producers` object and exactly this one is sent to the `slimFileProcessor`.

So, that's first: there is no `File` in the `payload` for the `FileWritingMessageHandler`. But we can fix it a bit later.

Now you have a log like:

> ServiceActivatingHandler#0)' produced no reply for request

So, your `slimFileProcessor` doesn't return something to be sent to the `outputChannel()` for potential file move from one directory to another.

If return something isn't possible by the logic at all, you can consider to use a `.publishSubscribeChannel()`. Make that `xmlBeanTranformer()` as a one subscriber and `fileOutboundChannelAdapter()` as another. This way the same `File` object will be sent to two branches. Only the point that the second branch won't be called until the first one finishes its work. Of course, if everything is done in the same thread.

You still can live with a simple linear flow, just because you get a gain of the `FileHeaders.ORIGINAL_FILE` header which is going to be used in the `FileWritingMessageHandler`. But you should keep in mind that last one supports only these types for request message payload: `File`, `InputStream`, `byte[]` or `String`. For your *move after process* use-case, of course, it would be better to deal with the `File` type. That's why I suggest to consider *publish-subscribe* variant.